# Friend likes not coming in Graph API in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the friend likes in graph api through android app. I am able to get the friend id,name without specifying fields attribute. (like this "/me/friends")

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("zumbvare", session.getPermissions().toString());

                if (session.isOpened()){

                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                          if (user != null) {


                            /*TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");*/
                          }
                        }
                      }).executeAsync();

                    new Request(
                            session,
                            "/me/friends",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new Request.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    /* handle the result */

                                    Log.d("Zumbare", response.toString());
                                    fbResponse=response.toString();
                                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                                    if (graphObject != null){
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                                        try{
                                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                                            Friend f;
                                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                                f= new Friend();
                                                 JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                                                 Log.d("Zumbare", "id = "+object.get("id"));
                                                 f.setID(String.valueOf(object.get("id")));
                                                 Log.d("Zumbare", "id = "+object.get("name"));
                                                 f.setName(String.valueOf(object.get("name")));
                                                 /*JSONArray a = object.getJSONArray("likes");
                                                 Log.d("Zumbare", "likes count : "+a.length());
                                                 f.setLikes(String.valueOf(a.length()));*/
                                                 friendList.add(f);

                                              }
                                            Log.d("Zumbare", "Friend list count : "+friendList.size());
                                        }catch (JSONException e) {

                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                           }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ).executeAsync();
                }






            }




        });
```

but if I add field attributes as "/me/friends?fields=id,name,likes" I am getting exception as

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}
```

I could get the permission string log as

```
[public_profile, basic_info, user_relationships, user_location, user_likes, user_activities, user_friends, user_about_me, user_status, user_tagged_places]
```

So could someone help me how to get friends likes ?

TIA

Comment: You can't. All friends_* permissions was removed in API v2.0

Comment: Actrually, I am looking for friends who accepted my app and made a log in & not all actual FB friends.

Are you saying friends_* permissions of my app itself not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can only retrieve likes of friends who have also granted `user_likes` permission in the application.